# Remove body element

Tags: javascript, html

How to remove HTML `<body>` element with all of its content?

```
var e = document.getElementsByTag('html');
e.removeChild('body');
```

Does not work.

Answer (score 17):

The simple solution would be

```
 document.body.innerHTML = "";
```

But why on earth would you want to do this?

**By the way:**

```
 var e = document.getElementsByTag('html');
```

should be

```
 var e = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
```

and

```
 e.removeChild('body');
```

should be

```
 e.removeChild(document.body);
```

Comment: "But why on earth would you want to do this?" suppose you wanted to just start over inserting stuff (new body...)

Comment: Thats pretty much a given, but I would guess that clearing the body is really only a symptom of bad design (code that is)

Comment: Just came across this looking for something else but a good reason you might use this is in an `afterEach` clean up in render tests where you're adding nodes in your tests.

Answer (score 13):

1. getElementsByTagName returns a collection of nodes, not a single node
2. removeChild takes a node, not a string containing a tag name

```
    var e = document.body;
    e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
```

… however HTML documents *require* a body element, so this may have unexpected behavior.

Comment: actually, chrome will allow it.

Comment: By the way, I'm guessing you mean 'getElementsByTagName **returns** a ..'

Comment: Chrome will allow what? You to remove the body element? Great. So that's one browser out of … lots (present and future). Corrected the typo.

Comment: Actually, any browser will allow removing the body element. That doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: It makes it a hilarious idea, though. You know, as long as your application isn't supposed to do anything serious.

Comment: Legitimate use case: unit testing. Wipe out the body element and recreate it during tests so you know you're starting with a clean document each time.

Answer (score 4):

I think this will remove it

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
html.removeChild(body);
```

Comment: this might mess up your global namepsace, btw..., probably need a `var` in here.

Comment: It should be getElementsByTagName :)

Answer (score 4):

...

```
document.body.parentNode.removeChild(document.body);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
document.body.parentNode.removeChild(document.body)
```

or

```
document.body = document.createElement("body")
```

or

```
while(document.body.childNodes.length != 0) {
  document.body.removeChild(document.body.childNodes[0])
}
```

Comment: Since someone just upvoted this code: For example 3 would probably be worthwhile to store document.body.childNodes to an array, then iterate down that for removal. Haven't done any benchmarks but that seems intuitive.

Comment: For 2, merely creating a `body` element isn't enough to delete the existing body.

Answer (score 3):

The `body` itself has a method which does just that:

```
document.body.remove();
```

Comment: How can i add <body> After Remove it

Comment: That's actually a good question, but this wasn't the question (as presented above). Not sure if there is an accessible setter for `document.body`; in even case, it is `null` after having removed it and it should be of type `HTMLElement`.

Comment: Okay Sir ,

Thank  you :)

Comment: @Dakopatel - see my answer which includes why removing `<body>` is sometimes called for, the quickest wy to remove it and how to add a new `<body>` after removing the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will remove all the content of body tag on click on the button
And if you want to remove content onload then use this  `onload="document.body.innerHTML = '';"`

```html
<html>
<body>
This is example Text<br>
<button onclick="document.body.innerHTML = '';">Click me to remove body contents</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several people on this page have asked why one might even wish to remove a `<body>` element from an `HTML Document`.

Admittedly, it's a seldom-seen approach, but it's almost always because one wishes to *remove* the current `<body>` from a document (while keeping the `<head>`) and then *create* a **new** `<body>` element (to follow the same `<head>` as before).

So why not, simply *empty* the existing `<body>` element via:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
```

or

```
while (HTMLSourceTab.document.body.firstChild) {

  document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
}
```

The answer might be:

If the `HTML Document` in question is being opened in a new browser tab, these processes (above) can *only* execute after the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires.

And they may not execute quickly enough to prevent a brief **Flash Of Legacy Body**.

Whereas:

```
document.body.remove();
```

will normally execute quickly enough after `DOMContentLoaded` to prevent that flash.

Once the legacy `<body>` has been removed, a new `<body>` can be created and added via:

```
let newBody = document.createElement('body');
document.documentElement.appendChild(newBody);
```

or (if adding an empty `<body>`) simply:

```
document.body = document.createElement('body');
```

---

**Full code for opening an existing document in a new tab, removing the existing `<body>` and adding a new `<body>`:**

```
myNewTab = window.open(myNewTabURL, '_blank');

myNewTab.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  myNewTab.document.body.remove();

  setTimeout(() => myNewTab.document.body = myNewTab.document.createElement('body'), 800);

});

myNewTab.focus();
```